# Can I use a PC to fake a printer?

Tags: windows, drivers, printer

So if i want to do a print job on another machine,the print job is sent to the "dummy printer",nor to a real one.I want to get the print image on the "dummy printer" and do some analysis.

Comment: You can do research on [Virtual printer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_printer).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, although in some ways, your question might duplicate the one at [Software printer](https://superuser.com/questions/655995/software-printer/656356#656356)

But if you want to print something on another computer, but generate it on your own, the best solution is a bit different.

Install the same type of printer to your own system;  set it to use the port FILE:   OR, when actually printing, you can checkmark the box for "print to file" and it will print to a file for the one job only.  Both options are shown below.

[image: FILE port]

Now when you print to that printer, it will stop and ask you for the filename to save.  The file will generally end in .PRN and will contain both the content and the control codes for the type of printer used.

To actually print the job on the other system, copy the file to that system and just drag it to the printer icon.  Depending on the type of printer connection, there are other ways to finally print it, but the basic concept is that the file is "copied" to the printer at that point, not "printed" to the printer.